# Unconfirmed BTC after 48H, 0.000119 Fee!

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

My BTC has been unconfirmed **for 48 hours now**.
I deliberately made a relative big fee of **0.0001119** and still no confirms.
Could anyone here PLEASE help me I'm getting kind of desperate.
Any miner that could push it, I will send him an extra fee.

**This is the transaction:** https://blockchain.info/nl/tx/f40f229b36f94bfbaa97a9998107c0014a6ad079370566698ec1cb58f2c94cb8

I would REALLY appreciate any help, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microtransactions can take pretty long, even with a relative big fee.

The confidence of your transaction is: 17.39% and miner preference is low:
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/f40f229b36f94bfbaa97a9998107c0014a6ad079370566698ec1cb58f2c94cb8/

At the moment there are a huge number of unconfirmed transactions:
https://blockchain.info/nl/unconfirmed-transactions

See also this site, it will show you the estimated confirmation time in minutes:
https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/#delay

But don't worry, you wont lose any BTC. If it takes too long you will get your balance back.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there any way to increase the confidence? I've had quite some succesful transactions in the past... Also the website I send it to will refund if the payment is confirmed within 30 days. Or will I get the refund nonetheless? Thanks again for your time.